# How can I edit a registry key with VB.NET or VB6?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, registry

I need to edit a registry key and set the data value to "4"

I know how to do it through the command prompt but am trying to find some Visual Basic code to do it.

If it helps, this is the key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR\Start

Comment: Are you trying to disable autostart of USB sticks preventing malware from being execute?

Answer (score 4):

Here's how'd you do it in Visual Basic .NET

```
    Dim key As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine
    Dim subkey As RegistryKey


    subkey = key.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR", True)

    subkey.SetValue("Start", 4)
```

You'll need to make sure to add

```
Imports System
Imports Microsoft.Win32
```

at the top of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it in Visual Basic 6 (or VBA)

Download this [registry editing code](http://refactormycode.com/codes/726-vb6-registry-editing-class) and put it into a class.

Then you can have code like the following to actually modify the value:

```
Dim reg As New RegistryClass

With reg
    .SetKeyValue .HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR", .RegDWORD, "Start", 4
End With
```

Comment: The link no longer seems to be valid

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx) class in the [Microsoft.Win32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.aspx) namespace. Check the docs, it is pretty easy to use.