# How to set permanent user environment variables?

Tags: vb6, environment-variables

How can you set permanent user environment variables from within VB6 code for an app that will be run under non-administrator rights?

I know of `SetEnvironmentValue` but apparently this only changes the vars for the current process which is insufficient for my needs.

Because the environment variables are possibly stored in the HKLM registry I am concerned that a non-administrator user running my app will not be able to set the env var.

Comment: You can't set system-wide variables without admin rights. if you could, it'd be trivial for a malicious app to subvert (say) the system PATH variable and force its own hostile DLLs be loaded instead of standard system ones. You can, at most, set variables for the current user.

Comment: @MarcB: I am talking about user environment variables, not system ones. Is there a method for setting them beyond the scope of the current process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the current user, environment variables are stored under `/HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Environment`, which shouldn't require elevated privileges.

Comment: I'm rusty with VB6, but this answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/492000/119549

Comment: When would the change be visible to processes?

Answer (score 2):

VB6 guru Karl Peterson has written a reusable module to handle setting user or system environment variables. See [here](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/08/18/persisting-environment-variables.aspx) from Visual Studio Magazine in 2009. [Direct link to code](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/raw/MEnvVars.bas.txt)

Comment: That link seems to be about folders and not env vars.

Comment: Do you think there might be any problems with this code, particularly the SendMessageTimeout call, being run by a non-admin user in quite a locked down environment?

Comment: @CraigJ I don't think so. Sending messages is fundamental in Windows. In this context, the SendMessageTimeout call is how we notify other processes that the environment variables have been changed. Supposing it did fail for some security reason, SendMessageTimeout would just return a zero value - no harm done to the rest of your program. It would just mean you don't have permissions to notify other applications that the ev has changed. Therefore you can't do it, there's no way round that. And it wouldn't prevent the ev actually being changed.

Comment: I have used Karl's code to set some user env vars (and using the alert function provided) but I am finding it takes a while for the env var change to take effect. I am finding that I have to restart the app for the changes to be seen. Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this handy class ages ago to do just what you asked.

http://www.vbrad.com/pf.asp?p=Source/src_environment.htm

Comment: I am finding that my app has to be restarted for the changes to a user env var to be seen by the app, even after using the `SendMessageTimeout` function. Is that expected behaviour?

Comment: @CraigJ Not really, it should theoretically work.  Is your app operating under the same user as the app that's doing the broadcasting?  Also, I wrote that code more than a decade ago.