# Modifying Registry values using Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, registry

I want modify settings of my window using VB. For example I want to change the color of File explorer's window title bar, menu bar etc. How to begin with modifying registry using VB and which entries to modify to change the color?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491890/how-can-i-edit-a-registry-key-with-vb-net-or-vb6

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend saving settings to file, for example app.config is designed for this purpose. If you prefer registry, then take a look into codeproject article [Application Settings the .NET way. INI, Registry, or XML](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8554/Application-Settings-the-NET-way-INI-Registry-or-X)